# uwsgi pidfile get deleted automatically

Tags: django, uwsgi, daemon

I have a nginx server setup with django and uwsgi.
There are multiple django apps run simultaneously on different virualenvs, separate uwsgi processes on separate ports on which nginx listens to.
The setup works alright.

I use pidfile flag to stop uwsgi processes. When I start the any uwsgi server, pidfile is created and I can immediately restart without errors with the script provided below.

**After while when I come back to update the server, the pidfile is gone and the uwsgi process is still running. This makes this approach useless.**

**project_A_uwsgi.ini:**

```
[uwsgi]
 master          = true
 socket          = /tmp/stripe_test_uwsgi.sock
 chmod-socket    = 666
 chdir           = /home/ubuntu/TestProjects/ProjectA
 wsgi-file       = /home/ubuntu/TestProjects/ProjectA/ProjectA/wsgi.py
 virtualenv      = /home/ubuntu/TestProjects/ProjectA/venv
 vacuum          = true
 enable-threads  = true
 daemonize= /home/ubuntu/TestProjects/ProjectA/uwsgi.log
```

**project_A_server_restart.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh

DEPLOYMENT_PATH='/home/ubuntu/TestProjects/ProjectA'

. ${DEPLOYMENT_PATH}/venv/bin/activate
uwsgi --stop /home/ubuntu/TestProjects/project_A_uwsgi.pid

uwsgi --ini /home/ubuntu/TestProjects/project_A_uwsgi.ini --pidfile /home/ubuntu/TestProjects/project_A_uwsgi.pid

sudo service nginx restart
```

What could be the reason for the pidfile to get deleted? how will I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with one of our server.
We have 2 servers with the exact same OS setups and the issue appear only on one of these servers.

Our configuration is uwsgi, Nginx & debian-11.

uwsgi.ini on the server whith no issues :

```
[uwsgi]
chmod-socket = 666
daemonize = /var/log/path/server_a.log
die-on-term = true
disable-logging = True
enable-threads = true
master = true
module = myapp.wsgi:application
pidfile = /tmp/myapp.uwsgi.pid
processes = 4
python-path = /var/www/path/myapp
socket = /var/www/path/myapp/uwsgi.sock
stats-http = true
stats-server = localhost:8084
strict = true
vacuum = true
```

uwsgi.ini file on the server with the issue (only nb of processes change):

```
[uwsgi]
chmod-socket = 666
daemonize = /var/log/path/server_a.log
die-on-term = true
disable-logging = True
enable-threads = true
master = true
module = myapp.wsgi:application
pidfile = /tmp/myapp.uwsgi.pid
processes = 16
python-path = /var/www/path/myapp
socket = /var/www/path/myapp/uwsgi.sock
stats-http = true
stats-server = localhost:8084
strict = true
vacuum = true
```